# How to count clicks on an image via onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html, image, onclick

I have an image with `onclick` event and want to count all clicks on the image and show the total number in an input bar.

Here's a piece of code I used that didn't work

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Krummpleanimator</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
//imageselection
    function buttonClick() {
      document.getElementById('gimper').stepUp(5);
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 40px;">
  <img id="gimper" src="paintbrush.png" width="200" height="200" alt="gimpybutt" border="5" onclick="buttonclick();">
    <input type="text" id="gimper" value="0"></input>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect the output to be an image that I clicked and an input bar on the side saying how many times I clicked but it just shows the image and the input bar next to it.

Could you please help me to achieve my desired result?

Comment: Do you have a `buttonclick` function defined in the javascript?

Comment: On image click you will call the function `buttonclick()` but this function is not present in your script. So it's normal that nothing append

Comment: I am new to stack overflow, This is not all of the code I also have this in the script section <script type="text/javascript">

    function buttonClick() {
      document.getElementById('gimper').onclick = buttonClick();
    }

</script>

Comment: Why are you binding an onclick listener when you click on the button? You should be incrementing, not adding another event listener

Comment: Your function defined name is "buttonClick" and used name is "buttonclick". Take care about letter cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need to implement a function called `buttonclick` that increments the value of the input.

Second, IDs are meant to be unique. Your image and input should have different IDs for `document.getElementbyId` to work.

```js
function buttonclick() {
  document.getElementById("gimper").value++;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 40px;">
  <img id="gimper_img" src="paintbrush.png" width="200" height="200" alt="gimpybutt" border="5" onclick="buttonclick();">
    <input type="text" id="gimper" value="0"></input>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

your markup:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 40px;">
    <img id="img" src="paintbrush.png" width="200" height="200" alt="gimpybutt">
    <input type="text" id="gimper" value="0"></input>
</div>
```

JS script:

```
<script>
  let image = document.querySelector('#img');
  image.addEventListener("click", function () {
    let inputValue = parseInt(document.querySelector('#gimper').value, 10);
    inputValue = isNaN(inputValue) ? 0 : inputValue;
    inputValue++;
    document.querySelector('#gimper').value = inputValue;
  })
</script>
```